# How to remove the values from chart.js

Tags: charts

How to remove values and that gray line from the stacked area line chart that is present on the left side of the chart. I tried to set the `fontSize` to 0 and nothing happens

```
    options: {
      responsive: false,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          stacked: false,
          ticks: {
            fontSize: 0
        }
        }],
        xAxes: [{
          stacked: false,
          ticks: {
            fontSize: 0
        }
        }]
      },
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

set the `display` to `false`...

```
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      display: false,  // <-- add this
      stacked: false,
      ticks: {
        fontSize: 0
    }
    }],
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a silly mistake. The right way of doing this is:

```
type: 'line',
      data: { }
      options: { }
```

I had written it as

```
 type: 'line',
       data: { 
        options: { }
       }
```